# Django save image data to database

Tags: sql, sql-server, django, database, imagefield

I am new to Django. Default behavior of Django is to save images to "media" and only save image path to database. Is there any way to change this behavior and save the image data itself to an sql-server database?

I have found some solutions but none of theme worked for me, like:

1) django-storages: I cannot find a complete example on how to implement this. I tried different things but I was not successful in making it work

2) use a binaryField: how can I have a custom field with a button to upload images from selected folder like for imageField and FileField?

Comment: Please read [ask], post the code you try to write, the error you received, etc

Answer (score 0):

From the wonderful book "Two Scoops of Django 1.11: Best Practices for the Django Web Framework"  by Audrie Roy Greenfield & Daniel Roy Greenfield:

> Storing files in a database field should never happen. If it’s being
> considered as a solution to a problem, find a certified database
> expert and ask for a second opinion.

To summarize PostgreSQL expert Frank Wiles on the problems with using a database as a file store:

➤ ‘read/write to a DB is always slower than a filesystem’

➤ ‘your DB backups grow to be huge and more time consuming’

➤ ‘access to the files now requires going through your app (Django) and DB layers’

More info in [this blog post](https://www.revsys.com/tidbits/three-things-you-should-never-put-your-database/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @nznm. I am aware of this. But unfortunately, this is a requirement for the project that I am working on.